# Mongo query: array of objects where a key's value is repeated

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongo. Posting this question because i am not sure how to search this on google

i have a book documents like below

```
{
  bookId: 1
  title: 'some title',
  publicationDate: DD-MM-YYYY,
  editions: [{
    editionId: 1
  },{
    editionId: 2
  }]
}
```

and another one like this

```
{
  bookId: 2
  title: 'some title 2',
  publicationDate: DD-MM-YYYY,
  editions: [{
    editionId: 1
  },{
    editionId: 1
  }]
}
```

I want to write a query `db.books.find({})` which would return only those books where `editions.editionId` has been duplicated for a book.

So in this example, for `bookId: 2` there are two editions with the `editionId:1`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework; specifically, you can use the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator to group the records together by book and edition id, and count how many times they occur : if the count is greater than 1, then you've found a duplication.

Here is an example:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$editions"},
  {$group: {"_id": {"_id": "$_id", "editionId": "$editions.editionId"}, "count": {$sum: 1}}},
  {$match: {"count" : {"$gt": 1}}}
])
```

Note that this does not return the entire book records, but it does return their identifiers; you can then use these in a subsequent query to fetch the entire records, or do some de-duplication for example.